# No image is displayed : python

Tags: python, image-processing

```
import pylab
import skimage
from skimage import io, color
import numpy as numpy

rgb = io.imread('img.jpg')
skimage.io.imshow(img)
```

i am trying to display an image using skimage. On executing, neither an image is displayed nor an error is shown. Can anyone tell me where am going wrong

Comment: Where the image is located?

Comment: its in a folder inside home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `skimage.io.show()` to show pending images.

Comment: it worked.Thank you. But why it didnt worked using skimage.io.imshow(img)

Comment: Following the documentation you are using non-interactive script. [You can read about it here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.show)